# In Python, using jsonpath-rw to get values for specific attribute (json/dict)

Tags: python, jsonpath

Here's my json:

```
{
   'test': [
        { "id": "1", "description": "Test 1" },
        { "id": "2", "description": "Test 2" }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the value for **id** where **description** is "Test 1".

I found the following example on the JsonPath page:

```
$..book[?(@.price<10)]
```

When trying to parse the following jsonxpath expression:

```
parse('$..test[?(@.description="Test 1")].id')
```

I get the following error:

```
jsonpath_rw.lexer.JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 7: Unexpected character: ?
```

What am I doing wrong? Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Oddly enough, looking at the [lexer code](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw/blob/master/jsonpath_rw/lexer.py), jsonpath-rw doesn't appear to support the `?(boolean)` filter mechanism at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that `jsonpath-rw` doesn't support this feature. Perhaps consider another library? [`ObjectPath`](http://objectpath.org/) looks promising:

```
>>> import objectpath
>>> json_obj = { ... } # This has to be pre-parsed
>>> tree = objectpath.Tree(json_obj)
>>> ids = tree.execute('$..test[@.description is "Test 1"].id')
>>> print list(ids)
["1"]
```

It doesn't quite follow the JsonPath syntax exactly, but it's quite similar, at least from a perfunctory survey. [Documentation](https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath) is also available.

Of course, if your JSON will always be in the same form (i.e. you won't have to deal with missing child objects, etc), then you could easily do the same query using a list comprehension, or something similar.

```
json = { ... }
ids = [t['id'] for t in json['test'] if t['description'] == 'Test 1']
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `..` operator (recursive descent/deep search) is very slow. Use `.` if you are sure that test is in the root of the document and only in the root of the document.